# Error: Assembly file '' does not exist! Load failed. - when trying to start .Net Micro 4.2 Project

Tags: visual-studio-2010, emulation, .net-micro-framework, netduino

I get the error "Error: Assembly file '' does not exist! Load failed." when I try to start a .Net Micro 4.2 Framework Project (in the emulator) in Visual Studio 2010.

I cannot set debug points to my main procedure (it crashes before it reaches it). And I have another micro project in the same solution, that starts without any problems.

Any idea where this meaningful error message comes from?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, I found it by myself:

There have been unsupported/wrong version (.Net) assemblies in the references of this project. I could use the "Unused References..." check and remove the unnecessary assemblies and now it works.